# What Javascript libraries have good support for syntax highlighting of OCaml code?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ocaml, sml

Ideally the library supports a wide range of languages in addition to OCaml, but good support for OCaml is the main requirement.

Comment: In my experience, most syntax highlighters are quite low-tech (regexp, keyword matching mostly) and it's not a lot of work to adapt an existing syntax coloring configuration to OCaml. A couple of hours at best.

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow is using [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). This library supports a lot of canonical languages as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints).

Although OCaml is not the main supported language, you can update [lang-ml.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-ml.js) to highlight OCaml syntax better.

Answer (score 5):

Using Js-of-ocaml you may use ocaml code for that.

For instance there is one in ocsforge ( http://ocsigen.org/darcsweb/?r=ocsforge;a=tree ):

It uses a patched ocaml lexer ( ocaml/parsing/lexer.mll and the patch src/ocaml_lexer.patch ).
The other usefull files for you are src/ocsforge_color.ml and src/ocsforge_color_tokens.ml{,i}

Comment: Do you think it would be easy to use this to display a session of TryOCaml (http://try.ocamlpro.com) ?

Comment: We should do a small separate project to be able to link that easilly, but there is no reason for this to be complicated.